# Perl - Convert integer to text Char(1,2,3,4,5,6)

Tags: perl, character-encoding

I am after some help trying to convert the following log I have to plain text.

This is a URL so there maybe %20 = 'space' and other but the main bit I am trying convert is the `char(1,2,3,4,5,6)` to text.

Below is an example of what I am trying to convert.

> select%20char(45,120,49,45,81,45),char(45,120,50,45,81,45),char(45,120,51,45,81,45)

What I have tried so far is the following while trying to added into the `char(in here)` to convert with the `chr($2)`

```
perl -pe "s/(char())/chr($2)/ge"
```

All this has manage to do is remove the char but now I am trying to convert the number to text and remove the commas and brackets.

I maybe way off with how I am doing as I am fairly new to to perl.

> perl -pe "s/**word to remove**/**word to change it to**/ge"
>
> "s/(char(**what goes in here**))/chr($2)/ge"

Output try to achieve is

> select -x1-Q-,-x2-Q-,-x3-Q-
>
> Or
>
> select%20-x1-Q-,-x2-Q-,-x3-Q-

Thanks for any help

Comment: @chb By all means, suggest other tools. Otherwise the purpose of your comment is unclear.

Comment: show the desired output for your example input

Comment: @chb Feel free to suggest another way if you have one. Gone with perl as it was something I have been playing around with a little bit. 

The main bit that I am trying to convert is char(45,120,49,45,81,45) and yes in perl it is chr(xx) the %20 I know most off the top of my head for the URL so not to fussed.

Answer (score 4):

There's too much to do here for a reasonable one-liner. Also, a script is easier to adjust later

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use URI::Escape 'uri_unescape';

my $string = q{select%20} 
    . q{char(45,120,49,45,81,45),char(45,120,50,45,81,45),} 
    . q{char(45,120,51,45,81,45)}; 

my $new_string = uri_unescape($string);  # convert %20 and such

my @parts = $new_string =~ /(.*?)(char.*)/;

$parts[1] = join ',', map { chr( (/([0-9]+)/)[0] ) } split /,/, $parts[1];

$new_string = join '', @parts;
say $new_string;
```

this prints

```
select -x1-Q-,-x2-Q-,-x3-Q-
```

Comments

- Module [URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/lib/URI/Escape.pm) is used to convert percent-encoded characters, per RFC 3986
- It is unspecified whether anything can follow the part with `char(...)`s, and what that might be. If there can be more after last `char(...)` adjust the splitting into `@parts`, or clarify
- In the part with `char(...)`s only the numbers are needed, what regex in [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) uses

If you are going to use regex you should read up on it. See

- [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), a tutorial
- [perlrequick](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), a quick-start introduction
- [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), the full account of syntax
- [perlreref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html), a quick reference (its [See Also](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#SEE-ALSO) section is useful on its own)

Comment: Thanks Zdim that is a great help

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Ouch, forgot about that :)  Btw, that is not aimed against anything and certainly not your answer; I've posted all kinds of "one-liner"s. (Even the ones that obviously aren't fit for production may be good to show an approach in a condensed and easy-to-try way.) Just thought that a full script is better for someone who is starting out with Perl.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. And you're right; your answer is much better for production code and especially for a beginner. My answer is really only good if you're for some reason doing this from the command line and not a script file.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is going to be a messy "one-liner". Assuming your text is in a variable called `$text`.

```
$text =~ s{char\( ( (?: (?:\d+,)* \d+ )? ) \)}{
    my @arr = split /,/, $1;
    my $temp = join('', map { chr($_) } @arr);
    $temp =~ s/^|$/"/g;
    $temp
    }xeg;
```

The regular expression matches `char(`, followed by a comma-separated list of sequences of digits, followed by `)`. We capture the digits in capture group `$1`. In the substitution, we split `$1` on the comma (since `chr` only works on one character, not a whole list of them). Then we map `chr` over each number and concatenate the result into a string. The next line simply puts quotation marks at the start and end of the string (presumably you want the output quoted) and then returns the new string.

Input:

```
select%20char(45,120,49,45,81,45),char(45,120,50,45,81,45),char(45,120,51,45,81,45)
```

Output:

```
select%20"-x1-Q-","-x2-Q-","-x3-Q-"
```

If you want to replace the `%` escape sequences as well, I suggest doing that in a separate line. Trying to integrate both substitutions into one statement is going to get very hairy.

Comment: Thanks Silvio will have a play around with that as well

Answer (score -1):

This will do as you ask. It performs the decoding in two stages: first the URI-encoding is decoded using `chr hex $1`, and then each `char()` function is translated to the string corresponding to the character equivalents of its decimal parameters

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'select%20char(45,120,49,45,81,45),char(45,120,50,45,81,45),char(45,120,51,45,81,45)';

$s =~ s/%(\d+)/ chr hex $1 /eg;

$s =~ s{ char \s* \( ( [^()]+ ) \) }{ join '', map chr, $1 =~ /\d+/g }xge;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
select -x1-Q-,-x2-Q-,-x3-Q-
```